# SQL bring number of count, another column basis problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, group-by

I have this table:

BANK -  BRANCH_NAME - ADDRESS - DISTRICT - CITY - PHONE - FAX - OPENNING DATE

How do I bring branches on a city basis?

[image]

What I expect is a city knows how many branches it has.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results. It is unclear what you mean by *on a city basis*.

Comment: MysQL or SQLite? Please tag only the one database that you are using.

Comment: I'm using microsoft sql server management studio

Comment: I added table example

Comment: what I expect is a city knows how many branches it has.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> what I expect is a city knows how many branches it has

You can use aggregation:

```
select city, count(*) no_branches from mytable group by city
```

If `(city, branch)` tuples are not unique in the table, then:

```
select city, count(distinct branch) no_branches from mytable group by city
```